# Selecting Multiple Sheets Simultaneously

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'd like to copy multiple sheets to another spreadsheet, [it doesn't seem](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/kCe8vT_omgw) selecting multiple sheets simultaneously is a feature. Is there a workaround, add on, perhaps an available script?

Answer (score 2):

The [Google app script](http://trevorfox.com/2014/09/bulk-hide-show-delete-multiple-sheets-google-spreadsheets/) and add on community continues to prove to be an industrious bunch, currently testing [Bulk Sheet Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bulk-sheet-manager/ncifcaeanmakefjdnkaiddkiecokhoka).

Update: unable to "copy to" another sheet, resorting to copying entire spreadsheet and bulk removing unwanted sheets with add on.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?
You make a copy of the original file. 
Then rename the new copy of the file to FILE#2. 
FILE#1 remains the same.
FILE#2 has a copy of all the sheets/tabs as FILE#1.
You then open FILE#2 and delete the sheets/tabs that you don't want.
Save FILE#2.
FILE#2 now has copies of the sheets/tabs from FILE#1. :)